# How to fetch the header values from columns that are not visible in ag-grid using protractor and typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor, ag-grid

I am trying to validate the headers of ag-grid columns.
The problem is that I am only able to read the headers of the columns that are visible.
For the rest of the columns (for which we have to scroll horizontally to see those), the values are coming blank.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
element.all(by.css(".ag-header-cell-text"))
  .map(function (header) {
    return header.getText()
  }).then(function (headers) {
  var i:number;
  var num:number=0;
  for(i=num;i<headers.length;i++) {
    console.log("ag-grid header details:");
    console.log(headers[i]);
  }
});
```

Output of this code is:

```
ag-grid header details:
Data
ag-grid header details:
Class
ag-grid header details:
Value2
ag-grid header details:
Element
ag-grid header details:
Value1
ag-grid header details:
Method
ag-grid header details:
Value3
ag-grid header details:

ag-grid header details:

ag-grid header details:

ag-grid header details:
```

Comment: It depends on what is your goal? You want to check what will see your user? Or you want to check that your DOM has right values?

Comment: perhaps the header text is populated only when the header becomes visible. If you are allowed, you could execute a scrollIntoView before the getText().

Comment: @Oleksii I want to validate the ag-grid header values and the row values.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, scrollIntoView is one of the options that i can use. But was wondering if there is any way without scrolling.

Comment: I do not know. Is there a sample page to which you could point us? I was finding it hard to duplicate with things I found on the web, because the program seems quite good at sizing stuff to content.